# Has anybody used Dragon Dictate on OS X with MacVIM

Tags: macvim, voice-dictation

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer and I've seen a very intriguing [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwKA-KJapBI) of a developer using [Dragon Dictate](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm) on Windows to do software development. I'm a long-time OS X / VIM user and I am wondering if anybody uses Dragon with MacVIM. Googling doesn't seem to turn up any results.

Comment: See also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup in the video is quite impressive.  I imagine that there was a lot of customization necessary to have the software work that way. Dragon Dictate works with vim for inserting text (I just tested this myself), but it doesn't do as well at navigation or editing the text, and it certainly can't do all the fancy code insertion straight out of the box. I imagine that if you have a disability that prevented the use of your hands that you would be motivated to make such an environment work, but I imagine that for normally-abled people it would take more work than it's worth.

Comment: And yes, this post was dictated with Dragon :)

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the test. Was this test with the terminal based vim or macvim which are two different packages actually.

Comment: I was thinking of a hybrid solution where I can use voice macros for common activities and fallback to keyboard for other things and grow my voice macros organically. Does this sound like a reasonable solution?

Comment: @bradphelan I tested with MacVim. If you can have your macros be triggered by text inserted, it could work

Comment: Out-of-the-box, Dragon Dictate is difficult to use with Mac VIM for anything but basic insertion. I'm currently trying to set up a number of custom Dragon Dictate commands that will make integration with Mac VIM more complete. If anyone already has a set of Dragon Dictate commands specifically for Mac VIM and would care to share them it would be much appreciated.